# Is there any way to offset curve and filling space between with mesh to make a ring?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to make some curved rings in Blender with realistic height and width and look as shown below. Can anyone suggest a way to do it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I find your question unclear.  Please provide more clarity.  Can you provide an example of what you want as an image?

Comment: I suggest you see a tutorial on shaping a mesh with Curve Modifier and Proportional Edit.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Taurus mesh to start with. You then can select the top and bottom ring of the Taurus to make it look like this.[image: Either this or turn a cylinder on its side.]
I Created more rings using cntl+r so I could use smaller sections.[image: Simple changes I am sure you can figure exactly what you want from here.] 
This isn't to complicated but the tutorials by: Blender Guru might help as they go over the basics and he makes a lot of objects. If you need tutorials that is.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYj6e-72RDs&index=2&list=PLjEaoINr3zgHs8uzT3yqe4iHGfkCmMJ0P
Final Image(I changed two or small things but this isn't really detailed so it isn't attractive.)[image]
Edit: I forgot to say then you can extrude from a plane and make it connect off of multiple extrudes.

Answer (score 0):

Select the curve and go to: curve settings > Geometry  tab
There are options to bevel (fill geometry)
And extrude (along z axis)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer your explicit question, you can use a bevel object to define any (constant) cross section you want:

[image]

This cross-section can be rotated by either rotating the bevel object in edit mode, or by adjusting the tilt values of the main "ring" curve.  The shape of the cross section cannot change over the course of the ring, but it can shrink and fatten (by changing the "radius" of the ring's control points.)

If you need the actual shape of the cross-section to change along the length of the curve, then it's necessary to use a curve-deformed mesh object.

Notice the particular curve I've used as a bevel object.  I've changed some handles to vector-type to create a flat section.

Your actual reference, however, is going to be more complicated than this, because the top of the ring branches.  That means that you won't be able to use a single curve to define that particular ring.